# Why global warming

Tags: cosmology

According to big bang , the universe is expanding . By this we can say that distance between sun and earth is increasing so it should happen that earth temp. Decrease but in real life what we see is global warming , why?

Comment: Expansion of the universe takes Billions of years. Climate changes in the hundreds/thousands of years range. It is all a matter of different time scales.

Comment: People please see the profile, that this is a 13 year old.

Comment: @annav I agree (at the risk of being slammed), and for a 13 year old - the question is actually pretty good (so are the answers in this +1 to everything here)

Comment: There are many factors involved in determining Earth's average temperature, the dominant ones that most matter are well established and well known. Universe expansion doesn't even figure into it. Basic reading about climate change is recommended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Universe has indeed been in the state of global cooling since its very birth. It started very, very hot. Right now, the cosmic microwave radiation that penetrates the space (it is a thermal radiation of a sort, like the red light you get from a heated piece of metal in your oven) has the temperature of 2.7 kelvins (-270 degrees Celsius or so).

Every ten billion years or so (the age of the Universe is 13.8 billion years), this temperature will drop to one-half; the drop is exponential (one-half, then one-quarter, one-eighth, and so on) because the expansion of the Universe is approximately exponential in time due to the positive cosmological constant that accelerates the expansion.

One must correct you: the expansion of the Universe doesn't mean that the Earth-Sun distance is increasing. The Solar System is a gravitationally bound one, by local forces, and those are not affected by the expansion of the Universe. The Earth-Sun distance may be extremely slowly changing due to other effects but the expansion of the Universe isn't one of them. So the expansion of the Universe really means that you may "store" an increasing number of solar systems into the Universe!

At any rate, the temperature 2.7 kelvins of the outer space is very cold and doesn't impact the Earth's temperatures much. The Earth's temperature is much higher than 2.7 kelvins – about 300 kelvins in average (15 Celsius degrees or so in average) – and it is this pleasantly warm because of the equilibrium between the incoming energy and heat from the Sun; and the outgoing thermal radiation emitted by the Earth.

It may be calculated that the equilibrium temperature at which the thermal energy emitted by the Earth is precisely equal to the incoming energy from the Sun is about 300 kelvins. The temperature depends on the place (especially the latitude: warm equator vs cold polar regions), daytime (day vs night), season (summer vs winter), and other factors.

Some of the factors are "systemic" and may change for extended periods of time. The reflectivity of the Earth's surface (albedo) affects the equilibrium temperature (a darker Earth would be warmer, like a dark asphalt in the summer), and so does the amount of "greenhouse gases" (gases that prevent the outgoing thermal radiation of the Earth to escape from its atmosphere). The greenhouse gases act like a "sweater" or a "blanket" that prevents you from freezing in a cold weather by allowing you to "keep" the body heat you produce.

The term "global warming" is a catchword for a nearly negligible expected (and perhaps partially observed, but this is controversial) rise of the temperature caused by the increasing concentration of the minor greenhouse gases in the atmosphere, especially carbon dioxide (CO2). The concentration is rising because people burn coal or oil, so carbon plus oxygen in the air creates carbon dioxide which is still gas that spends a century or so in the atmosphere.

The main greenhouse gas, water vapor (H2O), has concentrations that are almost exactly dictated by the temperature and other "external drivers". The water vapor as a greenhouse gas is responsible for about 30 Celsius degrees of extra warming on the Earth's surface because it prevents some of the outgoing heat from escaping. The Earth would be really cold and inhospitable without water vapor in the atmosphere.

Carbon dioxide (the main plant food - trees are not built out of the "soil" but largely out of the carbon dioxide they catch from the air, so carbon dioxide is, along with oxygen and water, the most important gas/liquid for life) is only causing 10 times less than that, about 3 degrees, and the dependence of the total warming caused by this gas is only increasing logarithmically. The more CO2 we have, the less important the newly added CO2 becomes. Since 1750, the concentration of CO2 in the atmosphere has increased by 40 percent and this has caused some increase of the average surface temperature on the Earth because the extra CO2 has prevented some heat from escaping from the Earth, too.

The total warming caused by the newly added CO2 since the beginning of the industrial revolution could have been something between 0.2 deg C and 0.8 deg C – the latter is the whole observed or estimated temperature change. The exact value is not known (it is about 1/2 of the so-called climate sensitivity) and the value, with potential political implications, is a highly controversial number.

Regardless of the exact value, this change in 250 years is a small fraction of a percent of the absolute temperature 300 kelvins on Earth and these sub-degree temperature changes cannot be felt by human beings even if they occur immediately. They surely cannot be felt if this change is divided to 100 or 250 years. One may only demonstrate that something about the temperature has been slightly changing if he carefully observes pretty much the whole globe for whole days, whole years, and for 50 years, with very accurate thermometers and evaluate the data with extremely careful and accurate algorithms. If any condition fails to be met, the changes of the temperatures up and down become equally likely.

So global warming is an academic contribution to the time derivative (change in time) of the global mean (average) temperature. Despite what you may hear in the media, it is negligible for practical purposes, there are many other sources with both signs the contribute to the temperature changes (solar activity and sunspots, ocean cycles, El Nino, volcano eruptions, changing composition of plants, and so on), but despite the negligibility of the "global warming", the temperature changes caused by the changing greenhouse gases and other factors are still many orders of magnitude (millions of times) greater than the changes of the Earth's temperature induced by the evolution of the whole cosmos, e.g. by its expansion. The Cosmos is large, heavy, and has many interesting properties, but for practical purposes, it doesn't really matter on the Earth. Only the Sun, the Earth's atmosphere, and oceans (and biosphere etc.) matter for the Earth's surface temperatures.

Comment: You should note that although this small change of temperature duo to human activities may not be *felt* directly, it surely has many other indirect effects that can affect life on the Earth even on rather short timescales.

Comment: Sadly, I cannot "note" it because it is not true and it is not possible according to the basic laws of Nature. If a temperature change can't be felt, it's surely way too small to "affect life on the Earth". Changes that are "consequential" are much larger than those that can be "felt".

Comment: *Changes that are "consequential" are much larger than those that can be "felt"* (1) the temperature scale of 'human feeling' is arbitrary (2) lots of inconsequential changes can sum up to consequential ones - or average out (3) earth is a chaotic system, so tiny changes do matter: it's possible that a minor temperature increase could trigger some process that exponentially accelerates global warming - or totally reverses it; personally, I've not seen convincing evidence that global warming cannot possibly be harmful as you seem to claim, so I'd be careful with such blanket statements...

Comment: No, Christoph, the fact that the Earth's atmosphere is a chaotic system implies that tiny changes *don't* matter, at least not in any predictable way in a predictable direction. A butterly wing in New York may improve the weather in Beijing but it may also make it worse. The chaotic character means that the noise is very important - and this is just a different way of saying that the underlying signals are *not* important. You should be much more careful about making or endorsing scientifically invalid calls for panic that may be very costly if not economically devastating.

Comment: @LubošMotl Interesting. I asked a question [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/95219/can-a-small-change-in-the-earth-temperature-give-rise-to-large-scale-effects) about it.

Comment: @LubošMotl: please use the @ so I get notified on further comments, and please stop putting words in my mouth: I made it *very* clear that the end result need not correspond to the starting direction; the point is that human-induced climate change could move us from a apparently reasonably stable region of phase space to a more chaotic one, and as you noted, this would mean that no one can know what the end result will be (cont)

Comment: the point is that we're involved in a huge one-shot experiment in geo-engineering without really understanding the rules of the game, and I find your absolutist claim that *If a temperature change can't be felt, it's surely way too small to "affect life on the Earth"* as insufferable as the bullshit Al Gore spouts - but he's a politician, so I didn't expect any better

Comment: also, please excuse me getting all defensive here - if some moderator were to decide that SE isn't the right place for these kinds of discussions, feel free to remove these ramblings (not that I could do anything about it if you decided to do so anyway ;))

Comment: Dear @Christoph, the one-shot experiment started 13.8 billion years ago with the Big Bang and the geo-engineering experiments have been constantly tried for 4.6 billion years. And yes, we only began to understand the rules of the game - the laws of physics - a few centuries ago. What's your point?

Comment: The temperature in the Universe have gone from $10^{32}$ kelvins to 2.7 kelvins of the cosmic microwave background. The temperatures on the surface of Earth right now go from -50 deg C in Northern Russia to +40 in Central Africa. People can reliably enough feel much smaller (by two orders of magnitude) temperature changes, comparable to 1 deg C, but this resolution is still too poor to feel the change of the global mean temperature in the last 100 years. My "absolutist" claims are just basic physics. One may find this truth inconvenient but it's the only thing he can do about it.

Comment: @LubošMotl: I chose the word experiment because it involves a supposedly rational experimentor, who should avoid doing experiments that results in his death ;) anyway, going by [Berkeley Earth](http://berkeleyearth.org/summary-of-findings), the increase in average land-surface temperature in the last 100 years is about $1K$, but I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to get at here; humans cannot 'feel' global warming happening - so what? the concern is medium-term consequences to the global ecosystem, including *future* human generations

Comment: Dear @Christoph, it was not you who chose the word "experiment" to hype indefensible worries about the "global warming". It was Bill McKibben, the Luddite activist from 350.org, in his book Eaarth, see http://news-oceanacidification-icc.org/2012/01/23/a-huge-experiment/ - Please don't try to take credit for other people's ideas even though they're just ideas how to sell propaganda. - So what? I am just saying the obvious fact that the worries are absolutely irrational and unscientific.

Comment: If they're hypothetical worries about the future generations, then please leave the problem to future generations who will know 10 times more about these issues than myself and 500 times more than you. But it is silly to extrapolate. The climate is a chaotic system and most of the changes are short-term noise that cancels over longer periods of time. If the temperature changes by less than 1 K in 100 years, it doesn't mean that it will jump by 10 K in 1,000 years. And the changes due to CO2 are slowing down due to the log character of the greenhouse effect, they'll be more and more negligible.

Comment: Otherwise your description of the reasons why you use the word "experiment" is completely wrong. The addition of CO2 is clearly not an experiment according to your explanation of the word "experiment" because the purpose of the addition of CO2 isn't to find anything, like experiments. The purpose of the increasing CO2 is that it is just a side effect of using fossil fuels and doing other things that are essential for practical reasons in the modern industrialized world.

Comment: I've used the picture of human activity on earth as an experiment in schoolroom discussions decades before some book I did not read got published by some guy I do not know, and I can assure you I wasn't the first person who used that imagery

Comment: *If they're hypothetical worries about the future generations, then please leave the problem to future generations who will know 10 times more about these issues than myself and 500 times more than you.* - condescension aside, that is an argument that could serve as basis for a rational discussion; however, the claim I responded to was *If a temperature change can't be felt, it's surely way too small to "affect life on the Earth"*; I'm stopping here, so feel free to get in another shot at having the last word

Comment: @Christoph, I understood what you have responded to. I just don't think that you have offered any valid counter-argument. It is not an accident that we may feel temperature changes that may impact our lives - that's how and why the sense has evolved.

Comment: The climate science denial in the answer and the comments shouldn't stand unchallenged. Downvoted.

Answer (score 4):

The distance between the Sun and the Earth isn't increasing. Well, that's not quite true, but it's increasing at only [7m per 100 years](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0508047), which is far too slow to have any significant effect on the Earth's climate.

While the Earth-Sun distance hasn't changed (much) the Sun has been getting gradually brighter throughout it's life. It's now about [25% brighter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aSolar_evolution_%28English%29.svg) than when the Earth was first formed. However although this is a big change it happens on too long a timescale to affect climate over say a hundred years.

So you need to look elsewhere for factors that can change the climate on short timescales.

Answer (score 0):

> According to big bang , the universe is expanding .

Yes, the models of how the cosmos came to be have a [big bang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang) and various expansions of space until our present time.

> By this we can say that distance between sun and earth is increasing

No, this is not true. The gravitational force between the earth and the sun is much stronger than the expansion of the underlying spacetime. Think of a balloon on which there are hard spots. When you blow it up the distances between spots becomes large, but not the spots themselves. The spots are clusters of galaxies, and we have observed their spread, but the clusters of galaxies  and their galaxies themselves are tightly bound by their gravitational field and are not becoming larger.

> so it should happen that earth temp.Decrease

The distance with the sun is not changing due to the expansion, the gravitational attraction to the sun does not change because the effect is very very small, so the temperature changes on the earth cannot be attributed to this.

> but in real life what we see is global warming , why?

The cooling and warming of the earth has been happening the past millions of years as measured by [icecore temperatures.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_age) . It is due to the orbit taken by the earth which is not fixed, and sometimes it is closer to the sun and sometimes further away.

The last ice age happened around  10.000 years  ago, and our warm time is called the [Holocene period](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holocene). We are due to fall to the next ice age within some hundreds , more or less, years. The recent warming of the world comes after a sharp cooling called "[the little ice age](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Ice_Age)"  . If you look at the [Holocene figure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aHolocene_Temperature_Variations.png)  you will see that variations of temperature are the norm, and not the exception.

Comment: It is known with high confidence what is causing current global warming and well established that it is exceptional, not normal. Downvoted.

Comment: @KenFabian science is not about partizan , football sides games, but about validation of theories with data. A lot of the currently popular "science" on global warming is not validated by data, but of course one must know what this involves.

Comment: -"variations of temperature are the norm, and not the exception" is not consistent with the current state of science on climate, which finds current change IS exceptional and due to anthropogenic causes. I haven't been active here, but I think Answers should not promote minority dissenting views on global warming as fact.